# Laravel 5 PHPUnit Testing - Wrapping All Tests Within a Controller Into a Single Transaction

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, laravel-testing

I have the following test file in my Laravel application:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ApiAuthControllerTest extends TestCase{

    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testLogin(){

        // Test login success
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/login', array(
            'email' => 'hello@yahoo.com',
            'password' => 'sometext'
        ))->decodeResponseJson();
        return $response['token'];

    }

   /**
     * @depends testLogin
     */
    public function testLogout($token){

        // Test logout success
        $this->json('DELETE', '/logout', array(
            'token' => $token
        ))->assertReponseStatus(200);

    }

}
```

I am using the `DatabaseTransactions` class to wrap my tests as transactions so they don't write to my database.  I noticed that using this class will wrap every individual test within my class as a transaction.

I would like to wrap the entire class as a transaction.  In my example above, I need for the token that was generated from my login request to be persistent in the database as I test the logout request.

How would I do this with Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible. Laravel refreshes the app instance on `setUp`/`tearDown`. In PHPUnit, these functions are run every test method. Thus, using transactions means there will be no persistence between test methods.

You can, however, generate the token again in your `testLogout` test. Since your logout test relies on a token to be present, there is nothing inherently wrong with that approach.